# Passing an expression by reference vs Passing variable by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, lvalue

In the code shown below, `func(a3)` enters the if condition and produces output "hi". However, different behavior is observed when the parameter to the function is an expression.

For example, `func(a1->right)` doesn't enter the if condition.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node {
   public:
    int data;
    Node *left, *right, *parent;

   public:
    Node(int data) : data(data) {
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;
    }
    ~Node() {}
};
void func(Node*& node) {
    Node* p = node->parent;
    p->right = node->left;
    if (node->left) {
        cout << "hi\n";
        node->left->parent = p;
    }
    node->parent = p->parent;
}
int main() {
    Node* a1 = new Node(10);
    Node* a2 = new Node(20);
    Node* a3 = new Node(30);
    Node* a4 = new Node(40);
    Node* a5 = new Node(50);
    a1->left = a2; a2->parent = a1;
    a1->right = a3; a3->parent = a1;
    a3->left = a4; a4->parent = a3;
    a3->right = a5; a5->parent = a3;
    /*
         a1
       /   \
     a2     a3
           /  \
           a4   a5
     */

    /* Case 1: prints hi */
    func(a3);

    /* Case 2: doesn't print hi */
    // func(a1->right);


    /* Case 3: prints hi */
    // Node* ptr = a1->right;
    // func(ptr);
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Reason for different behavior when **reference of expression** is passed to func as opposed to **reference of a variable**?
2. What is idiomatic way of passing **reference of an expression** to a function.

Edit: gdb output

```
(gdb) b 17
Breakpoint 1 at 0x555555554856: file pointer_ref.cpp, line 17.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, func (node=@0x555555767e80: 0x555555767ed0) at pointer_ref.cpp:18
18      Node* p = node->parent;
(gdb) p node->data 
$1 = 30 // a3
(gdb) n
19      p->right = node->left;
(gdb) p p->data
$2 = 10 // a1
(gdb) n
20      if (node->left) {
(gdb) p p->right->data
$3 = 40 // a4
**(gdb) p node->left->data
Cannot access memory at address 0x0**
// ^^^ This seems to be the problem location
// After changing p->right to node->left,
// somehow, node->left becomes null 
(gdb) p node->left
$4 = (Node *) 0x0
(gdb)
```

Comment: As an aside, do not include `bits/stdc++.h` because it brings in all the things, when you only want to bring in a few of the things.

Comment: Points noted @AndyG.

Comment: I see the issue now. You should step through this with a debugger and watch what your tree looks like. I will say that there's no reason to receive your ptr by reference in `func`.

Comment: You modify the thing you pass in. So maybe it is related to the order in which you make the different function calls.

Comment: What is the reason you are passing the pointer by reference? Beside making your code over-complicated.

Comment: [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wU_Gg9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed reference to `a1->right`. So any changes you make to that field are seen in that function. The `p->right = node->left;` actually sets `a1->right` to a different node.

In the case 3, you pass reference to a local variable `ptr`, which does not get changed,  since it is a copy.

If you add:

```cpp
    cout << "node was " << node << std::endl;
    p->right = node->left;
    cout << "node is " << node << std::endl;
```

You will see that your node changes.

Comment: Then why does node->left become null (please refer to newly included gdb output).

Comment: `node->left` becomes null, because `node` now points to a different node now, which does not have a left chidl. a1->right is a3, so node->left is a3->left at that time, which is a5. a5->left is NULL. (I hope I got that correct)

Answer (score 0):

> Reason for different behavior when reference of expression is passed to func as opposed to reference of a variable?

Reason is the convoluted logic you have in your program. In this particular case when you either pass `a3` or `a1->right` either pointer points to the same object, but `func()` itself modifies `a1->right` so when reference to `a3` passed that changes does not affect `node` but when `a1->right` passed it does. Hense the difference.

> What is idiomatic way of passing reference of an expression to a function.

There is no problem of passing reference the way you do, problem is overcomplicated data relationship. For example in your case there is no reason to pass this pointer by reference.